# Minimum Specs For Android Studio

Tags: android

My system configuration: Core i5 2,5 ghz with 4GB RAM. I have installed Android Studio but it is sluggish, I'm new in android development. Is upgrading RAM to 8GB help?

Comment: Upgrading to 8GB RAM is very good before that try the below method once  @Azzamzaine

Comment: just upgrading RAM to 8GB is sufficient

Comment: Upgrade your HDD to SSD first. Then thinking about RAM.